# How to check current value of boolean HTML attributes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, properties, attributes, boolean

Specifically "checked" for a checkbox element. If I include checked, it's true, if I don't, it's false.

If I include it and check `elem.attributes`, it will give me an object that includes a property called checked, which has a value of "checked" (like so `{checked: checked}`. If it's not included, there's no checked property.

However, if I look at elem.checked, it will always say true or false. Where can I see that value in the console without specifically doing elem.checked? Where can I see it in a list of properties?

If I do `Object.getPrototypeOf(elem)`, it says checked: (...). If I clicked the ellipsis it says

> "[Exception: TypeError: Illegal invocation at
>   HTMLInputElement.invokeGetter (:2:14)]"

EDIT: I got this far:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`document.getElementById("myElement").hasAttribute("checked");`

**EDIT**

If you just want to print it

`console.dir(element)`

Comment: That checks if it has the attribute but doesn't show me a list. Here's an image of what i want https://prnt.sc/nesrez